# HSQLDB: org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TRIGGER_CATALOG

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb, dbunit

I was trying to use DBUnit in our project and was running into a problem. Was wondering if you would be able to help with it.

Im using @ExpectedDatabase("file.xml") annotation, and while processing that, Im at this execution point:

```
at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:295)
at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTable(DatabaseDataSet.java:314)
at com.github.springtestdbunit.assertion.NonStrictDatabaseAssertion.assertEquals(NonStrictDatabaseAssertion.java:43)
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.verifyExpected(DbUnitRunner.java:130)
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.afterTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:70)
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:165)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:416)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:91)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
```

I have multiple tables in file.xml, two of which are organization and triggers.
When organization table is being processed, the metaData object returned at this line has exactly 3 columns as I expect: organization_id, name and status. These are the 3 columns that my organization table has.

But while processing triggers, at the same execution point, metaData is null, so it executes further to line 299 and calls:

```
// Create metadata and cache it
metaData = new DatabaseTableMetaData(tableName, _connection, true, super.isCaseSensitiveTableNames());
```

This meta data that is returned has a lot of columns that I dont have on my table (TRIGGER_CATALOG, EVENT_MANIPULATION, ACTION_TIMING, etc)

Expected columns (I have these in my schema):

```
TRIGGER_ID
TRIGGER_EXTERNAL_ID
TRIGGER_NAME (First occurrence. See below)
STATUS
CREATED_BY
CREATED_ON
UPDATED_BY
UPDATED_ON
```

Unknown columns (I dont have these in my schema):

```
TRIGGER_CATALOG
TRIGGER_SCHEMA
TRIGGER_NAME (Yes, This appears twice on the meta data. On the top probably from my schema, and here from reserved info/magic??)
EVENT_MANIPULATION
EVENT_OBJECT_CATALOG
EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA
EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE
ACTION_ORDER
ACTION_CONDITION
ACTION_STATEMENT
ACTION_ORIENTATION
ACTION_TIMING
ACTION_REFERENCE_OLD_TABLE
ACTION_REFERENCE_NEW_TABLE
ACTION_REFERENCE_OLD_ROW
ACTION_REFERENCE_NEW_ROW
CREATED
```

Due to this, it throws an exception:

```
org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TRIGGER_CATALOG
  at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTable(DatabaseDataSet.java:323)
  at com.github.springtestdbunit.assertion.NonStrictDatabaseAssertion.assertEquals(NonStrictDatabaseAssertion.java:43)
  at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.verifyExpected(DbUnitRunner.java:130)
  at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.afterTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:70)
  at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:165)
```

Is this happening since Im using the word "triggers" for my table name? Is triggers this a reserved keyword in DBUnit or HSQLDB? If I look at other tables in the DatabaseDataSet._tableMap hashmap, all the other tables seem to be healthy and have the columns that I expect in their corresponding metadata objects.
The maven entries Im using are:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Test class looks like:

```
public class TriggerServiceTest extends DBBaseTest {
    @Autowired
    private TriggerService triggerService;
    @Test
    @DatabaseSetup(value={"classpath:testData/trigger/Trigger_Test_2_Init.xml"}, type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT)
    @ExpectedDatabase(value="classpath:testData/trigger/Trigger_Test_2.xml", assertionMode = DatabaseAssertionMode.NON_STRICT)
    @DatabaseTearDown(value={"classpath:testData/trigger/Trigger_Test_2_Init.xml"}, type = DatabaseOperation.DELETE)
    public void testTriggerWrite(){
        TriggerDTO triggerDTO = new TriggerDTO();
        triggerDTO.setName("Trigger_Test_1");
        triggerDTO.setId("101");
        String newId = triggerService.write(triggerDTO);
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

And DBBaseTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:wfxSpringDatabaseTest.xml" , "classpath:wfxTriggerContextTest.xml"})
public abstract class DBBaseTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    @Before
    public void setApplicationContext() {
        ApplicationContextHolder.setTheGlobalAppContext(applicationContext);
    }
}
```

testData/trigger/Trigger_Test_2.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
    <organization organization_id="1" name="MyOrg" status="Active"/>
    <users user_id="1" username="admin" password="pwd123" email="abc@abc.com" full_name="The Admin" status="Active" created_on="2013-08-17 03:45:44.0" created_by="1" is_admin="1" secret_question="What is your favorite sport?" secret_answer="Quiddich" enabled="1" organization_id="1"/>
    <triggers trigger_id="101" trigger_EXTERNAL_id="101" trigger_name="Trigger_101" status="Active" created_by="1" created_on="2014-08-26 11:34:25.625" updated_by="1" updated_on="2014-08-26 11:34:25.625"/>
</dataset>
```

testData/trigger/Trigger_Test_2_Init.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
    <organization organization_id="1" name="MyOrg" status="Active"/>
    <users user_id="1" username="admin" password="pwd123" email="abc@abc.com" full_name="The Admin" status="Active" created_on="2013-08-17 03:45:44.0" created_by="1" is_admin="1" secret_question="What is your favorite sport?" secret_answer="Quiddich" enabled="1" organization_id="1"/>
    <triggers/>
</dataset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed that this was happening due to the word "triggers". This is probably a reserved keyword in HSQLDB. Upon changing it to "triggers_table", everything worked fine. Refer to the following link for all reserved keywords in HSQLDB:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/lists-app.html